# Is SHA-1 secure for password storage?

Tags: cryptography, hash, sha1

**Conclusion:** SHA-1 is safe against preimage attacks, however it is easy to compute, which means it is easier to mount a bruteforce or dictionary attack. (The same is true for successors like SHA-256.) Depending on the circumstances, a hash function which was designed to be computationally expensive (such as bcrypt) might be a better choice.

---

Some people throw around remarks like "SHA-1 is broken" a lot, so I'm trying to understand what exactly that means. Let's assume I have a database of SHA-1 password hashes, and an attacker whith a state of the art SHA-1 breaking algorithm and a botnet with 100,000 machines gets access to it. (Having control over 100k home computers would mean they can do about 10^15 operations per second.) How much time would they need to

1. find out the password of any one user?
2. find out the password of a given user?
3. find out the password of all users?
4. find a way to log in as one of the users?
5. find a way to log in as a specific user?

How does that change if the passwords are salted? Does the method of salting (prefix, postfix, both, or something more complicated like xor-ing) matter?

Here is my current understanding, after some googling. Please correct in the answers if I misunderstood something.

- If there is no salt, a rainbow attack will immediately find all passwords (except extremely long ones).
- If there is a sufficiently long random salt, the most effective way to find out the passwords is a brute force or dictionary attack. Neither collision nor preimage attacks are any help in finding out the actual password, so cryptographic attacks against SHA-1 are no help here. It doesn't even matter much what algorithm is used - one could even use MD5 or MD4 and the passwords would be just as safe (there is a slight difference because computing a SHA-1 hash is slower).
- To evaluate how safe "just as safe" is, let's assume that a single sha1 run takes 1000 operations and passwords contain uppercase, lowercase and digits (that is, 60 characters). That means the attacker can test 10<sup>15</sup>*60*60*24 / 1000 ~= 10<sup>17</sup> potential password a day. For a brute force attack, that would mean testing all passwords up to 9 characters in 3 hours, up to 10 characters in a week, up to 11 characters in a year. (It takes 60 times as much for every additional character.) A dictionary attack is much, much faster (even an attacker with a single computer could pull it off in hours), but only finds weak passwords.
- To log in as a user, the attacker does not need to find out the exact password; it is enough to find a string that results in the same hash. This is called a first preimage attack. As far as I could find, there are no preimage attacks against SHA-1. (A bruteforce attack would take 2<sup>160</sup> operations, which means our theoretical attacker would need 10<sup>30</sup> years to pull it off. Limits of theoretical possibility are around 2<sup>60</sup> operations, at which the attack would take a few years.) There are [preimage attacks against reduced versions of SHA-1](http://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/publications/article-1146.pdf) with negligible effect (for the reduced SHA-1 which uses 44 steps instead of 80, attack time is down from 2<sup>160</sup> operations to 2<sup>157</sup>). There are collision attacks against SHA-1 which are well within theoretical possibility ([the best I found](http://www.secureworks.com/research/blog/index.php/2009/6/3/sha-1-collision-attacks-now-252/) brings the time down from 2<sup>80</sup> to 2<sup>52</sup>), but those are useless against password hashes, even without salting.

In short, storing passwords with SHA-1 seems perfectly safe. Did I miss something?

**Update:** Marcelo pointed out an article which mentions [a second preimage attack in 2<sup>106</sup> operations](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/304). (*Edit:* As [Thomas explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772014/is-sha-1-secure-for-password-storage/2774744#2774744), this attack is a hypothetical construct which does not apply to real-life scenarios.) I still don't see how this spells danger for the use of SHA-1 as a key derivation function, though. Are there generally good reasons to think that a collision attack or a second preimage attack can be eventually turned into a first preimage attack?

Comment: This is now 7 years old and a lot has happened since it was last edited.  SHA-1 is no longer considered sufficiently secure for password hashing

Comment: @GordonM what happened? With the growth of computing power, SHA-1 collision attacks are becoming more and more practical but they are not really relevant here. SHA-1 was never really secure for password hashing (fast hashes generally aren't), but to the extent it was, it still is AFAIK.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: SHA-1 is as secure as you can get. MD5 would be fine too, even MD4; but it could make some investors nervous. For *public relations*, it is best to use a "better" hash function, e.g. SHA-256, even if you truncate its output to 160 or 128 bits (to save on storage cost). Some of the [SHA-3 round-2 candidates](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/Round2/index.html) appear to be faster than SHA-1 while being arguably "more secure"; yet they are still a bit new, so sticking to SHA-256 or SHA-512 would be a safer route right now. It would make you look professional and cautious, which is good.

Note that "as secure as you can get" is not the same as "perfectly safe". See below for rather lengthy explanations.

**About known attacks:**

The known attacks on MD4, MD5 and SHA-1 are about collisions, which do not impact preimage resistance. It has been shown that MD4 has a few weaknesses which can be (only theoretically) exploited when trying to break HMAC/MD4, but this does not apply to your problem. The 2<sup>106</sup> second preimage attack in the paper by Kesley and Schneier is a generic trade-off which applies only to very long inputs (2<sup>60</sup> bytes; that's a million terabytes -- notice how 106+60 exceeds 160; that's where you see that the trade-off has nothing magic in it).

The rest of this message assumes that the hash function you use (e.g. SHA-1) is a "black box" with no special property that the attacker may use. That's what you have right now even with the "broken" hash functions MD5 and SHA-1.

**About rainbow tables:**

The "rainbow attack" is actually cost-sharing of a dictionary or brute force attack. It is a derivative from the [time-memory trade-off](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.120.2463&rep=rep1&type=pdf) first described by Hellman in 1980. Assuming that you have *N* possible passwords (that's the size of your dictionary, or 2<sup>*n*</sup> if you consider brute-forcing a hash function with an output of *n* bits), there is a time-sharing attack in which you precompute the *N* hashed passwords and store them in a big table. If you sort the hash outputs, you can get your password in a single lookup. A *rainbow table* is a smart way to store that table with a much reduced space. You store only *N/t* hashed passwords, and you crack passwords with O(*t*<sup>2</sup>) lookups. Rainbow tables allow you to virtually handle precomputed tables much larger than what you can realistically store.

However, rainbow or not, the attacker still has to run the full attack at least once. This can be viewed as several successive optimization layers:

1. The brute-force / dictionary attack has cost *N* for cracking each password.
2. With a pre-computed table, the attacker pays that cost *N* **once** and can thereafter attack **many** passwords with very small extra cost per password.
3. If the pre-computed table is a rainbow table, then *N* can be somewhat bigger, because *storage* cost is reduced. The bottleneck on *N* becomes the CPU power that the attacker can muster, not the size of his harddisks.

If *N* is large enough that the CPU-cost of hashing *N* passwords is ludicrous, then such an attack is not feasible, regardless of whether rainbow tables are used or not. This means that a (preimage-resistant) hash function with an output of 80 bits or more is enough to make brute-force attack infeasible.

**About salts:**

Salts are a way to defeat pre-computations. In the description above, the salt brings back the attacker to step 1: salting prevents the attacker from sharing the O(*N*) cost between several attacked passwords. Pre-computed tables, *a fortiori* rainbow tables, are no longer feasible.

You want salting because when the hashed data consists in *passwords*, i.e. something which fits within the brain of a random human being, then *N* can be quite low: humans are really bad at choosing and remembering passwords. This is what "dictionary attacks" are about: that's using a reduced space of potential passwords (the "dictionary") under the assumption that many user passwords will be in that specially selected space.

Hence salting will at least prevent the attacker from using pre-computed tables, in particular pre-computed rainbow tables. This assumes that the attacker *will be* able to break one password or two; we do not want him to break 1000 other passwords with little extra overhead.

Also, salting is good for public relations.

**About SHA-1 cost:**

The elementary cost of SHA-1 is about hashing a 64-byte block. That's how SHA-1 works: data is padded, then split into 64-byte blocks. The cost of processing a single block is about 500 clock cycles on an Intel Core2 system, and that's for a single core. MD5 and MD4 are faster, count about 400 and 250 cycles, respectively. Do not forget that most modern CPU have several cores, so multiply accordingly.

Some salting schemes prescribe huge salts; e.g. what enters the hash function is actually 40000 successive copies of a single 128-bit salt, followed by the password itself. This makes password hashing more expensive (by a factor of 10000 with my example), both for the legitimate user and for the attacker. Whether this is a good idea depends on the setup. For login on a desktop system, this is good: the user will not even notice that it took 10ms to hash his password, instead of 1µs; but the cost for the attacker has risen by a very noticeable factor 10000. On shared servers with thousands of clients per second, the aggregate cost may become prohibitive. Conceptually, raising the bar by the same factor for the legitimate user and the attacker is not ultimately good security; but it can be a worthwhile idea in some specific situations.

**About online attacks:**

All of the above is about defeating *offline* attacks. An offline attack is an attack where the attacker has all the data he needs in order to "test" passwords; e.g. the attacker could get a copy of the database holding the hashed passwords. In an offline attack, the attacker is limited only by his computational resources. Conversely, an *online* attack is an attack where each guess by the attacker must go through an honest verifier (e.g. the attacker simply tries to log in on the attacked system). Online attacks are thwarted by enforcing limits on how many passwords can be tried per second. Extreme examples are smartcards which shut down after three wrong PINs.

Usually, for password security, it pays off much more to arrange the system for not letting an attacker build an offline attack. That's what Unix systems do: the hashed passwords, which used to be in the world-readable `/etc/password` file, are now in the `/etc/shadow` file which is protected against read access, except by a few privileged applications. The assumption here is that if the attacker can read `/etc/shadow`, then he probably has enough control over the system that he does not really need passwords anymore...

Comment: Excellent answer. The only bit I'd disagree with is "Conceptually, raising the bar by the same factor for the legitimate user and the attacker is not ultimately good security" - the attacker has to do a large multiple of the operations a user has to do. Adding one clock cycle for a user login adds millions for an attacker.

Comment: Is this still accurate? News is claiming that the Livingsocial hackers got the actual passwords from sha-1 encryption.

Comment: @Thomas This remains accurate and probably will remain accurate for the indefinite foreseeable future. Hackers can guess actual passwords through *any* sort of hashing due to the poor quality of common passwords. Guess "123456" and you'll always get a few hits. This will remain true no matter what password storage you use.

Comment: @Thomas, no matter what hashing method you use, if a hacker spends enough cpu and time sooner or later it will be cracked. Its not "how do we prevent it" its "how do we make it take enough time so the hacker wont bother".

Comment: Just my point of view, but why would you stick with SHA1, when stronger password encryption is already widely available? A year ago, MD5 was considered "secure", and now it's not - the same could happen to SHA1 any day now, for all we know. Personally, I am going to bet on Blowfish from this point forward - it seems to have a better rep and fewer concerned experts in the crypto-community, it's available almost anywhere, so there is no reason to gamble with SHA1.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. I'd give you another +1 if I could taking the time to us a µ in µS

Comment: @Peter Why make it easy? Using something such as PBKDf with a random salt and a large iteration count really drives the war factor up and the crack time way out. Consider 0.2 sec per password attempt.

Comment: @zaph i never said he should make it easy i just told him he is asking the wrong question.. But yes PBKDf is not a bad choice but if the hacker wants the password bad enough he will be able to crack it..

Comment: @Peter Please explain: "crack it".

Comment: @zaph bruteforcing until the right password is found.

Comment: You will not brute force PBKDF in any time (end of universe?) unless very extenmely excessively lucky. The only attack it to try known passwords and even then with a reasonable iteration count that should allow only 10 to 100 attempts per second per CPU core. If the input is not a known password this will fail.

Comment: @zaph your logic is fundamentally flawed, if you can make 1 attempt no matter the time, then you can crack it its just a matter of time... so no you can't say `If the input is not a known password this will fail.`. that's ignoring the factor that the next cpu's generation will be faster? and also ignoring any bugs that might be found in PBKDF.. I'm not saying you shouldn't try, just that you should never think you found a 100% secure solution...

Comment: Let's see, say PBKDF2 with iterations to take 0.1 sec on a iPhone (HW engine computes SHA256 in 2.5ms). 128-bit output (~10^38). Future assumptions: 1,000,000 CPU cores, 1,000,000x faster, total: 1,000,000,000,000 or 10^12 faster. Seconds in a year: ~10^7. Time: 10^38 / 10^12 / 10^7 / 10^1 = ~10^15 years or 1,000,000,000,000,000 years. But the hash most probably only needs to be secure for less than 100 years so there is still a wide margin of safety: 10^13.

Comment: I am shocked to my core to stray across an answer from @ThomasPornin saying MD5 is secure for password storage. If MD5 is fine, why does EVERYTHING say don't use it, use bcrypt?? Are they being overcautious? I have read and understood everything and was under the impression MD5 was very bad because so vulnerable to brute force. Comments as recently as a year ago do not contradict the answer...

Comment: I see OP's "conclusion" reiterating this point at top of original question, but am still somewhat confused to see this answer unchanged.

Comment: @Aerovistae: you might want to have a look at [that answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/655) on the security.SE site; it contains more analysis and recent details on password hashing.

Comment: SHA-1 collision attacks are now possible as of Feb. 2017. See my answer below.

Comment: @Aaron: however, collisions have no impact whatsoever on the security of password hashing.

Comment: SHA-1 can now be brute-forced with enough GPU processing power

Comment: @GordonM: SHA-1 collisions have no impact whatsoever on the security of password hashing.

Comment: @ThomasPornin Who said anything about collisions?  They can be brute-forced with enough GPU time, especially if you take into account how bad people typically are at picking passwords.  While a better hash wouldn't fix people being bad at picking passwords it would at least forestall the brute-forcing problem.

Comment: Despite the bounty award and hundreds of upvotes, I have to give -1. There is no discussion of length extension attacks, which is a huge vulnerability if you're not aware. You can of course avoid it by using proper HMACs, but the internal workings of SHA1/MD5 can be fiddled with to leak information, and should not be viewed as a random oracle like you can with SHA3/Keccak.

Answer (score 30):

The previous answers don't make any mention of GPUs, which can parallellise SHA-1 hashing to the extent that an entire database can now be brute forced in minutes or hours rather than days or weeks, even if the passwords have been salted.

Modern password hash algorithms such as bcrypt or scrypt are designed specifically to be difficult to run on GPUs due to the fact that they are block ciphers with much higher memory requirements (and memory access in a GPU can not be parallellised to the same extent). They also have a "work function" which allows them to be made slower on the fly as technology improves.

In short, you should only use the best tools for the job. And SHA-1 falls very far short of the state of the art.

For further reading:

- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/400/why-cant-one-implement-bcrypt-in-cuda
- http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage/6415#6415

Comment: *"Modern password hash algorithms such as bcrypt or PBKDF2 are designed specifically to be difficult to run on GPUs"* - did you mean "bcrypt or scrypt"? PBKDF2 is just iterated hashing, there is nothing in it that would be problematic to a GPU.

Comment: Please let me know what GPU you use, I will buy the same one. If you can do 2^160 SHA-1 computations in "minutes" (that would be less than "hours", so at most 59 minutes), you need to be able to perform more than 10^44 per second. Since PCIe transfers cap at around 128GT/s, your GPU must have awesome on-board memory too. I want it.

Comment: Ever heard of a dictionary attack?

Comment: @Damon: average password entropy is a few dozen bits at most, nowhere near 160 (see e.g. [this study](http://cups.cs.cmu.edu/rshay/pubs/passwords_and_people2011.pdf)). So if you don't need to brute-force all of the passwords, just most of them, a million calculations per second per password should suffice.

Comment: @Damon: So are you saying that just because some **users** leave their doors open, **lock makers** are therefore justified in making unnecessarily weak locks?

Comment: @Jammycakes: No, I'm saying that if users have a 1-foot thick steel door and leave that door open, lock makers should not be afraid that someone might use a sledge hammer and try to bash the door in.

Comment: @Damon: You seem to be assuming that users either have "trivial" passwords (<8 bits of entropy) or "unbreakable" passwords (>60 bits of entropy). You're completely ignoring everyone in between whose password entropy is in the 10-60 bit range. Those are the users where bcrypt, rainbow tables and GPUs, and they make up typically about 80% of a typical user base.

Comment: (oops... I should have said, "Those are the users where bcrypt, rainbow tables and GPUs make the biggest difference")

Comment: For some statistics and analysis, see http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/06/brief-sony-password-analysis.html - while 36% of users choose passwords that appear in password dictionaries, only 2-3% choose the most common ones.

Answer (score 8):

SHA1 is a **message digest**, it was **never** meant to be password-hashing (or key-derivation) function. (Although it could be used as a building block for a KDF, such as in PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1.)

A password-hashing function should defend against dictionary attacks and rainbow tables. A good password hashing scheme should also prevent an attacker from gaining an advantage by using a GPU, a FPGA or an ASIC. Several algorithms have been designed to achieve these goals.

Currently, the best choice is probably *Argon2*. This family of password hashing functions won the Password Hashing Competition in 2015.

If *Argon2* is not available, other choices include *scrypt* and the older *bcrypt*. Lastly, if none of these can be used,  *PBKDF2*, which is an oldish NIST standard, is still a much better option than using a message digest as a password hashing function.

Wikipedia has pages for these functions:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2

Answer (score 7):

Your description sounds accurate for the current state of the art.

You shouldn't be using a single iteration of any hash function, though: At the very least, you should iterate many times (1000 iterations of the hash increases the attacker's work 1000-fold. It increases your work by the same amount, but you're doing a lot less password hashing than they are).

Ideally, however, you should use an existing password storage primitive, such as those described [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20080822090959/http://www.matasano.com/log/958/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-secure-password-schemes/).

Comment: Iterating thousands of times is not as good an idea as you might think. It increases the risk of a hash collision. http://yorickpeterse.com/articles/use-bcrypt-fool

Comment: That article looks thoroughly confused. A secure hashing function doesn't lose appreciable entropy through iterative hashing, and iterative hashing is a core component of key stretching schemes such as PBKDF2 and scrypt. Even bcrypt, which the author recommends, uses a similar construction. His 'attack' relies on finding a preimage of a hash - in which case, most constructions using that hash are thoroughly broken anyway. Finally, I don't recommend people use iterative hashing directly - as I say in my question, you should use an existing primitive designed for the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Serious vulnerabilities have been discovered in SHA-1 that make the search much faster than brute force. It is still largely intractable, but that isn't expected to be the case for too much longer; paranoid programmers favour something from the SHA-2 family.

From [this article](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html) regarding the original 2005 result:

> "It's time to walk, but not run, to the fire exits. You don't see smoke, but the fire alarms have gone off."

It's not that the current cryptanalysis makes SHA-1 unsafe, but rather that the crypto community is worried that worse news might be just around the corner. This fear also applies to SHA-2, which exhibits the same flaws as SHA-1, albeit over a much larger search space, hence the ongoing quest for [SHA-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3).

In short, SHA-1 is safe right now, and probably will be for some time come, but the crypto community is uncomfortable with the prognosis.

Comment: Could you provide a link? As I said, the best preimage attack I could find makes search a whopping 8 times faster, and even for that to work you need to omit half the steps of SHA-1. (Also, I think that is a second preimage attack, which is useless against password hashes.)

Comment: I am also skeptical of something that comes from the NSA, in light of recent news :)

Answer (score 3):

If you store the salted password, SHA-1 is fine for practical purposes.
SHA-2 is considered more secure, but SHA-1 is not a problem unless you have a reason to be truly paranoid.

Here is what NIST [says](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/shs/hash_standards_comments.pdf):

> The results presented so far on SHA-1
>   do not call its security into
>   question. However, due to advances in
>   technology, NIST plans to phase out of
>   SHA-1 in favor of the larger and
>   stronger hash functions (SHA-224,
>   SHA-256, SHA-384 and SHA-512) by 
>   2010.

Comment: That is a NIST comment from 2004. Their [2010 draft recommendation](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-131/draft-800-131_transition-paper.pdf) says SHA-1 is approved for all non-digital signature generation applications beyond 2010.

Answer (score 3):

As of Feb. 2017, SHA-1 should no longer be considered secure. Google has reported success with collision attacks against the full, non-reduced-round SHA-1 ([link to report](https://sites.google.com/site/itstheshappening/)). For Google's announcement, [click here](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html).

Edit: As pointed out by others, passwords are not vulnerable to hash collision attacks. However as a general guideline I would not choose SHA-1 for security-related applications. There are better alternatives out there.

Comment: OK, finding a SHA-1 collision took approximately **6,500 CPU years and 100 GPU years**, it is not a production attack. Cracking a passwords are not a brute force against all possible inputs but against lists of 10,000,000 frequent passwords. [Here is the paper](https://shattered.io/static/shattered.pdf).

Comment: The flaw is using only any hash function to protect passwords. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security, cryptographic hashes are very fast. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: Collision is not preimage and passwords are not signatures. Collision attacks do not work against passwords because they require knowledge of the original plaintext.

Comment: Tgr: agreed, thank you. Zaph: Yes, salting to safeguard against rainbow attacks and using slow crypto hashes are among the recommended practices that I didn't specifically address in this answer.