# salt and crypt assistance

Tags: php, html, sql

i got my login page, and on it I am also using it to autheticate both username and password.

im stuck on checking the password against that provided in the database. This is because I've done this code in my registration for more security.

```
$hashed_password = crypt('pass1');
```

Would anyone be able to assist me in creating a if statement to check the database encrypted password to that of the user provided. I really appreciate it.

in the login page....this is my password post.

```
$password = htmlentities(trim($_POST['password']));
```

Comment: no need to trim password, what if user wants whitespaces to be a part of his password

Comment: @E_p: Interesting point; I kinda feel that in almost every case an extra space would be a mistake by the user.

Comment: Using htmlentities is mad though!

Comment: No need to screen password! You never store it "as is" anyway, Why limit user?

Comment: i only allow numbers,letters, undersocres and a dash. no white spaces. isn't html entities suitable here?

Comment: You should allow any symbol for password

Comment: PHP 5.5 will introduce [a new password hashing API with secure defaults](http://www.php.net/archive/2012.php#id2012-11-15-1). There is also [a PHP 5.3.7+ compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) which does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
// let the salt be automatically generated
$hashed_password = crypt('mypassword'); 

// You should pass the entire results of crypt() as the salt for comparing
if (crypt($user_input, $hashed_password) == $hashed_password) {
   echo "Password verified!";
}
```

**EDIT**

crypt() takes two paramaters, and second is so called salt ([see wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)). If not provided, salt will be autogenerated (hence can be considered random). Salt is used in the whole alghorithm, therefore to compare you want to `crypt()` user provided password with the same salt you did before otherwise result will be different. To make this possible salt is added to crypt result (at the begining) so providing previous result for comparion purposes simply feeds `crypt()` with old salt (it is either 2 or 12 chars depending on alghoritm used).

Comment: thanks for the response! I was wondering what does user input varialbe actually do there?

Comment: isnt crypt more secure. my goal here is to reduce brute force as much as possible

Comment: why do that? his only trying to help. and when your learning a new language you take all information on board from more experienced people

Comment: @PeeHaa What's wrong with `sha1`? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2772014/1741542 says it's still good enough for password storage.

Comment: had another read up on php.net, apprently sha1 shouldnt be used as crypt is normally more slower to break down.

Comment: @OlafDietsche 1. `sha1` is meant to be fast (which is bad for hashing passwords). 2. sha1 [has known weaknesses](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html). 3. there are way better tools for the job (see my comment under OP)

Comment: Ah, forgot sha1 been broken.