# mysqli query in login page

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

i think i have a problem with my crypt(); php function. No errors show up in my error log.

Im having difficulties when it comes to authenticating a login page.

```
   if( $page_mode == 'Login' )
{
require "globe.php";
    //simple post from below
    $username = htmlentities(trim($_POST['username']));
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $username);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Username = '$username'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $dbuser = $row['Username'];
    $dbpass = $row['Password'];
    $hashed_password = crypt($password, $dbpass);




    if( ($username == '') || ($password == '') ) {
        $error_string .= '<font color=red>You have left either the username or password field blank!</font>';
        }
    else if ($numrows == 0)
    {
        $error_string .= '<font color=red>No username can be found!</font>';
        }
    else if ($numrows == 1)
    {

       if ($password == $hashed_password)
       {
       $error_string .= '<font color=red>Details checked out</font>';
       }
    }
    else {
            $error_string .= '<font color=red>There was an error. Please contact an Admin</font>';

    }
}
```

None of the error stings display when I test it when i put in a username and password.

Would be grateful if anyone can resolve this

Should mention the error only started coming with the check of dbpass with usepass

Comment: What is your problem? Which error is displaying?

Comment: No errors are displaying. I purposely set one of the error messages to "details checked out" to see if it was working. Problem is I don't believe it to be authenticating

Comment: How do you know authentication is failing?

Comment: if ($password == $hashed_password)
       {
       $error_string .= '<font color=red>Details checked out</font>';
       }
it should have displayed "details checked out" if password and username was correct. Nothing does get displayed

Comment: can you edit your question with your function `crypt();`

Comment: isn't the crypt function there.   last line in the variables called $hashed_password

Comment: How does this relate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13536475/1741542?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$dbpass = $row['Password'];
$hashed_password = crypt($password, $dbpass);

if ($password == $hashed_password)
```

This compares the clear password from the login form to the hashed password.
But you must compare the hashed password against the hashed password stored in the database. So, this should be

```
if ($hashed_password == $dbpass)
```

because in the database, only the hashed password is stored.

For debugging purposes, you should echo `$hashed_password` and `$dbpass` to see what and how this is wrong. [`Crypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) states also, that crypt might fail if given an unsuitable salt. The returned string will then be less than 13 characters long.

Comment: so how does that check against the user password that was inputted. I tried that line you showed but had no luck. Thanks for posting though

Comment: @Bobski I have updated my answer to clarify the idea behind my proposed change.

Comment: thanks for the response. I carried out some debugging and came across this.
db pass 
$1$MUMIxjyq$XBvB1QAvXmayWvVmRqTbC0
pass 
********
hshpas 
$1$MUMIxjyq$RoZKifwj6UmCrHhnFFM0u0

Seems that the salt works fine at the start but breaks down?

Comment: @Bobski If your clear password is really "\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*", it's not surprising that it differs from the stored one. Now you must find out, where the password is changed to "\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*".

Comment: clear password isn't that, its worldofwars, even if it was that and it was correct to what the database has, it should still display the same output in hash. this is whats puzzling me -.-

Comment: @Bobski That's strange, when I crypt your password with this salt, I get an entirely different third hash. Did you create all the hashes on the same or different machines? I'm out of ideas. Anyway, whatever it is, I learned a lot on the way :-)

Comment: same machine same host same eveything. I have a strange feelings its something right in front of me. Database password hash gives a longer password then the encrypted one on the login page. Both at the start for first 8-10 characters have same letters then it changes after

Comment: @Bobski This is as it should be. These common characters are the salt. The hashed passwords, you have shown above, have the same length. So nothing wrong here either.