# Generating SHA-2 certificate with ikeyman

Tags: http, ssl, certificate

Trying to move from SHA-1 SSL to SHA-2 SSL since SHA-1 certificates expiring as of Jan 2016.
I am using ikeyman version 8.0.344 to generate a new SHA-2 cert.
Couple of questions I have

1. I am generating kdb, and under Create new Key and cert request I have selected:

   key Size: 2048,

   Sig. Algorithm: SHA2WithRSA

   Are these 2 values correct selections?

2.After created the cert. request, I viewed what I generated and seeing

Fingerprint (SHA1 Digest):

num:num:num...

Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA

Does it matter if FingerPrint is SHA1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the certificate can be forged. But, I am still researching so don't know if there is a known 'fix' or is this a non-issue for SSL security.

This question and ensuing discussion may shed some light - 
[Is SHA-1 secure for password storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772014/is-sha-1-secure-for-password-storage)